# Custom Adapter for MultiAutoTextView

Tags: android, filter, custom-adapter

I have implemented the a custom adapter for my MultiAutoCompleteTextView. It is filtering just the way I want but the results are not displaying as i filtered. I think there is something to do with publishResult(..) method but I am unable to figure out.

```
public class customConAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

private Filter filter;
List<String> sublist=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> conlist = new ArrayList<String>();
public customConAdapter(Context context, 
        int textViewResourceId, List<String> conlist) {
    super(context,  textViewResourceId, conlist);
    this.conlist = conlist;
    this.sublist = conlist;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null){
      filter  = new myFilter();
    }
    return filter;
  }

private class myFilter extends Filter
{


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
    {
        Log.i("in perfrom filtering",constraint.toString());
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
      /*  if ((constraint == null) || (constraint.length() == 0))
        {


                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();

        }
        else*/

           String constr =  (String) constraint.toString();
            final List<String> newItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String temp : conlist)
            {
                if ( ((java.lang.String) temp).toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                {   Log.i("the item of list that contains the constraint is"    ,(java.lang.String)temp);
                    newItems.add(temp);
                }
            }
            results.values = newItems;
            results.count = newItems.size();

            publishResults(constraint,results);

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results)
    {
        if (results.count > 0)
        {
            sublist=(ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: *the results are not displaying as i filtered* - care to explain? Also don't call yourself the `publishResults(constraint,results);` method in the `performFiltering()` method, just return `results`. Also your `sublist` should be a **copy** of `conlist` which will be used as a copy of the full items passed to the adapter(so you'll have in the `Filter` the full set of the initial values).

Comment: I am sorry if asking a dumb question but how can I set "sublist" as the newlist for adapter in Filter? and I want to make the filter able to show results for substrings too..

Comment: See this: `if (results.count > 0) { clear();
for(String item : results.values) { add(item);}}`

Comment: sorry but tried but not working as iteration through results.values is not possible..

Comment: Cast it to an `ArrayList<String>` : `if (results.count > 0) {ArrayList<String> data =(ArrayList<String>) results.values;clear(); for(String item : data) { add(item);}}`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
 if ( ((java.lang.String) temp).toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
```

with this one

```
 if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(constr))
```